# Gridview ImageButton change image on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview in which I have an Imagebutton. It shows the image based on hfComplete (a hiddenfield) value.

If the value is true, it shows "images/completeiconfixed.png" and attach the attribute to onmouseover "this.src='images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png';"

If it is false it shows "images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png" and attach the attribute to onmouseout "this.src='images/completeiconfixed.png';"

So far it is working fine for only first time. It loads the images fine and when I mouse over first time it change the image but second time it does not.

Any idea how to make it working on every mouse over and out. My code is bellow.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgComplete" runat="server" CommandName="completeRecord" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskID") + "," + Eval("Completed")%>' 
            Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="mycol-md-3px mycol-xs-3px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected void grdNetwork_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton imgComplete = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgComplete");
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(hfCompleted.Value) == true)
        {
            imgComplete.ImageUrl = "images/completeiconfixed.png";
            imgComplete.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png';");
        }
        else
        {
            imgComplete.ImageUrl = "images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png";
            imgComplete.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='images/completeiconfixed.png';");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get the behavior that you want by setting `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` in both cases:

```
protected void grdNetwork_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton imgComplete = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgComplete");
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(hfCompleted.Value))
        {
            imgComplete.ImageUrl = "images/completeiconfixed.png";
            imgComplete.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png';");
            imgComplete.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='images/completeiconfixed.png';");
        }
        else
        {
            imgComplete.ImageUrl = "images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png";
            imgComplete.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='images/completeiconfixed.png';");
            imgComplete.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='images/completeiconfixed_transparant.png';");
        }
    }
}
```