# Gridview row highlight and image change onmouseover in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, highlight, onmouseover

I can find different ways to highlight rows of gridview onmouseover, but I can't figure out how to change the imageUrl property of an imagebutton inside the row. I have a gridview with alternate row background and 2 imagebutton in cell 0. Images are red, highlight color must be red, so when row is highlighted I want to change images to alternative ones that are white. How to achieve so? This is one example I found for row highlight, can you please add to this the image changing thing? 
Also, how to trigger Delete command with confirmation dialog on the highlighted row when imagebutton is pressed? Thank you

```
Protected Sub gvHrEmploye_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        ' when mouse is over the row, save original color to new attribute, and change it to highlight color
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#EEFFAA'")

        ' when mouse leaves the row, change the bg color to its original value   


        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This post may help you to toggle the button image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238194/gridview-imagebutton-change-image-on-mouseover-and-mouseout/37241209#37241209.

Comment: That will changes the image url when onmouseover is on the button, I need to do the same but when onmouseover is anywhere on the row (when the row is highlighted). I probably need to change this part of code "e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#EEFFAA'")" adding like button.imageurl="\something.png"